# Hide a single file in a public repository on Github

Tags: git, github

Is it possible to make a single file or directory invisible (make it hidden) in a public repository on Github?

Comment: No. What would the point of that be? Keep the file out of version control, or make the repository non-public.

Answer (score 0):

No. Read permissions are granted at the repository level, not the directory or file level. This is the nature of Git.